# Can I assign the coordinate that convolutional filter works on?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pytorch

I do not want the conv kernel to slide every pixel in the image, I only need to to do conv operation on the pixels I assigned. For example, on a 224 x 224 image, normally the conv operation will slide all 224 x 224 = 50176 pixels. However, if I only want it to do conv on (15,67), (34, 90), (143,201)...., how can I do it?
BTW, I want these operations all run on GPU.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you know in advance the areas you're interested in, extract and work with these patches, not the whole image

Answer (score 1):

If you have the kernel `K` (of shape `H_k x W_k x C_in x C_out`) and the image `I` (of shape `MB x H x W x C_in`) and you have a position where you want to apply the kernel `h, w` then you don't need to use a convolution, you can just apply the kernel directly with a broadcasting matrix multiplication:

```
Out = torch.matmul(I[:, h:h+H_k, w:w+W_k, None, :], K.unsqueeze(0))[:, :, :, 0, :]
```